# Amazon EC2 VM Import Connector Backup Strategies

Tags: amazon-ec2, backup, vmware-esxi, amazon-web-services, disaster-recovery

I'm trying to get information on this connector but most of what i'm [finding](http://blog.eight02.com/2011/03/how-to-install-amazon-ec2-vm-import.html) seems to be rather old info.  My ultimate goal is to have my production virtual machines (esx 5.1) backed up to EC2 servers that can be spun up and reprovisioned in the event of some sort of onsite emergency.  So basically my question

1. Is it possible to do some form of scheduled differential backup with this connector ?
2. Is there a better way to do this ?
3. If not how else could I accomplish this.

p.s. need to use amazon.

### Edit

I'm using veeam for onsite backup (don't want to use the cloud edition).  Is it possible to mount a veeam backup to EC2 off of an s3 volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Amanda and Backula, both are opensource and will allow you to restore to a previous state.